# Can I solder two 12 VDC fans to one end of wires of single Molex connector?

Tags: soldering, 12v, fan

I have 2 Sunon fans (12 V, 415/519 mA - max, 5.4 W/6.22 W - max). I want to solder both onto the end of a single Molex connector cable extension (bought from a local store).

Molex connectors all-4 18AWG cable of the PSU. The PSU specs for the 12 V rail: Imax = 25 A, P = 15 W.

I don't think it's a good idea; for that reason I search help and advice.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMztE.jpg
I want ot solder both fans (2 wires 12v on the yellow single end and 2 wires black on black ground all together) this is my idea? Good bad?
https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/276/0050291758_CRIMP_HOUSINGS-160250.pdf

Comment: Please link the data sheet for the connector and maybe show a phot of the "end" you want to solder.

Comment: What advice you seek? The only question is can you solder, and that's not what we can know. Try modifying the question to what you want to know.

Comment: For a normal PC power-supply - sure. The fan startup and steady state current are trivial for normal PC fans. Server 80x38 9000 RPM fans are a different story.

Answer (score 0):

We have no idea what your soldering skills are like.

But there's no reason why you shouldn't connect both fans to a single Molex connector.  They only draw about an amp between them.

Make sure that the soldered joints are insulated, so they don't short together.  Heat shrink tube is probably the neatest option.